# How to prepare a PHP postgreSQL request with 'LIKE' keyword

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, symfony, prepared-statement

i'm using Symfony4 and a postgreSQL database. i'm working on a search system. I would like to check if something match with the string i'm sending with ajax in my database. But the SQL query always returns false. How should i do to make this code works ? Thanks for help :)

```
 public function search(Request $request) : Response {

        if($ajaxRequest = $request->getContent())
        {
            $requestContent = json_decode($ajaxRequest, true);

            $content = $requestContent["content"];

            $connexionParams = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb user=myuser password=mypassword";

            $db = pg_connect($connexionParams);

            $sql = pg_prepare($db, 'search_query', "SELECT nom, lon, lat, id FROM site WHERE nom LIKE $1 OR id LIKE $2");

            $result = pg_execute($db, 'search_query', array($content, $content));

            var_dump($content, pg_fetch_row($result), $result);

            $results = array();

            while($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
                $results[] = $row; 
            }  

            if(($results)) {
                return new JsonResponse([
                    'result' => true,
                    'results' => json_encode($results),
                ]);
            } else {
                return new JsonResponse([
                    'result' => false,
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If either `pg_prepare` or `pg_execute` fails, there *should* be an error. Can you include it?

Answer (score 0):

`false` means failure, not empty zero hits as stated [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-execute.php). Most likely there is an error in your SQL Syntax or connection data. Maybe [pg_last_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-last-error.php) helps to find the mistake:

```php
if ($result === false) {
 echo pg_last_error($db);
}
```